# Laptop Overheating - Possible Fan Malfunction?

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, overheating

for a while now my PC has been starting to lag because of CPU throttling. Using some software, I can see that my CPU temp is usually sitting at around more than 75 degrees C. This is quite concerning because I can't watch YouTube video's or do an online class without CPU throttling lagging out my PC. The first thing that comes to my mind is that my fan isn't working (I don't even know if I have one anyways - [specs](https://www.byodstore.com.au/Products/Product/207)). Please note that my computer has been shut off multiple times without warning (due to overheating). Any possible ideas on why this is happening? Can it be that I don't have a fan? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: 75 degrees is nothing for a CPU, you should only start getting worried at 90 degrees. Why do you think that the problem is overheating? Look in the Event Viewer for more information.

Comment: @harrymc I am concerned because when I simply watch a video, my cpu excels 80 degrees

Comment: maximum temp on that processor is 105°C, so it's nowhere near max. It is also a very slow CPU, so expect it to always have to work hard to keep up.

Comment: 80 degrees still doesn't explain CPU throttling or shutdown. Look in the Event Viewer for more information.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of your CPU actually thermally throttled?  Task Manager should provide the frequency, if it's below the base clock, that means it's being throttled.  As others have indicated, 75-85 degrees centigrade, is not a temperature you should be worried about.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the heatsink and re-paste the processor/heatsink. The paste assists with cooling and can dry out over time. Also purchase a can of compressed air and use it to clean the heatsink fins.